# Angulartics2 run error on build with Piwik

Tags: angular, matomo, angulartics2, piwiktracker

After updating Angulartics2 to 7.0.2 and run my project, it throws an error as follows:

```
Type '(typeof Angulartics2Piwik)[]' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Angulartics2Settings>'.
```

I've imported everything in app module and component it was running before so I don't know if its a bug or something that should be added after this update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Angular 7, you actually don't need to add it to `forRoot()`, just simply leave it blank like this:

```
Angulartics2Module.forRoot()
```

Here you can read more about [the forRoot convention](https://angularfirst.com/the-ngmodule-forroot-convention/)